# Add a new empty page

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, blank-page

I have a `.tex` file which is like my main,

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}           
\usepackage{times}                               
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{programsp}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{name}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}    
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newcommand{\decel}[4]{\langle#1, #2, #3, #4 \rangle}
\newcommand{\tod}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\llor}{\vee}

\newtheorem{Example}{Example}\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Algoritmo}{Algoritmo}

\normalbaroutside

\begin{document}
%%The text
\input{section}
\input{references}
\end{document}
```

However after a page of information like my name, and school I want an empty page, I am doing:

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
```

But this does not work. How do I change it so it works?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
```

gives an empty page. `\null` is defined as `\hbox{}`. This is needed because TeX doesn't create a pagebreak if there is *nothing* on the page. 
You can define an own command:

```
\newcommand*\NewPage{\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}
```

Comment: By following your steps, I create a new page but without the page number. Any way around it? Thanks.

Comment: that obvious! Delete the  `\thispagestyle{empty}` if you want a page number

Answer (score 12):

`\cleardoublepage` may also be of help, it brings you to the next available odd page, given the document is typeset in the `twoside` mode (default in the standard `book` class, for instance).

Comment: It was useful for me to use `\cleardoublepage\null` (in a double-sided document).

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` does not work for me. Maybe it works only in specific conditions.

Answer (score 10):

`article` class has `titlepage` option which prints title, author and date on its own page and starts text on second page. `book` class print a title page and start chapters on right-hand pages leaving and empty page after title page. `report` class does the same with the `twoside` option.

Answer (score 2):

This might be one of the blind ways to achieve a blank page, but I guess it works just fine in all cases.
Just add the following line at the end of text after which you need a blank page

```
\chapter*{} \thispagestyle{empty} \addtocounter{page}{-1}
```

Comment: `chapter` is not available in the article class.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you don't want that blank page to be counted then it would be -1

Comment: For whatever reason, THIS is the answer that worked for me. Thanks a lot! :)