# blank page without number page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, blank-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a new empty page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34934/add-a-new-empty-page)

I would add to my latex document a blank page.I tried using `\newpage` but I receive as result a new blank page with page number at the bottom. How can I create a blank page in the way the next page receives the correct number page?

Comment: Use `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: I tried \newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage but the next first page has as number page 2 and not 1 because latex consider blank page as a page. How can I fix numbers page?

Comment: @Mazzy: Also add `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` on the blank page.