# Page pair and odd of numbering

Tags: header-footer, numbering, page-numbering, fancyhdr

First, sorry for my english.

Hi, Im doing my final project in the University and I need some help with this features of my document.

How can I put pair numbers in the right side of the document and odd numbers in the left side of the document, in the numbering?

I want some like this pictures where you can see when I start a new chapter the numbering is in the middle of the page in the bottom.

Pair numbers of numbering are in the left side and Odd numbers of numbering are in the right side.

Note: In the first picture ignore the image with a number twelve, the important of this image is the number 5 and the start of chapter.

Im a newbie in Latex and I dont know what packages I have and I dont care so much. If you say me one package to use I will add that in my project.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{} 
\chead{}
\rhead{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\textit{\nouppercase \leftmark}}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt} 

\fancypagestyle{detailed}{
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introducción}

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Second Section}

\lipsum[1-7]

\section{Third Section}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

I think the problem is here

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{} 
\chead{}
\rhead{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\textit{\nouppercase \leftmark}}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
```

And If you compile my code you can see what I want. I want the number one of numbering in the middle of the page because is a new chapter like a the images.

The number two of the numbering should be in the left side and the number three in the last page should be in the right side.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that gives a skelton document for what you want. Currently we have to guess what document class, packages, fonts etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`.  Also what "pair numbers" do you want on the left and right hand sides? Are these page numbers?

Comment: You can have blank pages, completely empty, *but* they will need to be numbered. Otherwise, the internal page logic is confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a new empty page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34934/add-a-new-empty-page)

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: Hi, I edit my post and I put a example of what I want.

Comment: @J.Cabello That is an image of what you want, not an example of what you tried so far. Please look at this link: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I edit my post again, is that a MWE? O I need do more changes. The problem what I have is that I dont know how put an example what I want because I dont know do what I want in latex

Comment: @J.Cabello Yes, that's an MWE, I'm voting to reopen your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `article` class defaults to one-sided layout, so I recommend you switch to two-sided:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
```

However, since you're using `\chapter`, the `article` style is inappropriate. I suggest you switch to `book` (or a more sophisticate book-like class, such as `memoir`). In the case of `book`, the `twoside` option is the default.

> I want the number one of numbering in the middle of the page because
>   is a new chapter

The `book` class automatically puts the page number in the centre at the start of each chapter.

> The number two of the numbering should be in the left side and the
>   number three in the last page should be in the right side.

The header and footers need to specify the left and right settings for even and odd pages for double-sided documents:

```
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\textit{\nouppercase \leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\thepage}}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\textit{\nouppercase \leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt} 

\fancypagestyle{detailed}{%
 \fancyhf{}%
 \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textcolor[gray]{0.5}{\thepage}}%
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introducción}

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Second Section}

\lipsum[1-7]

\section{Third Section}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image: image of first page]

[image: image of double-page spread]