# Hide page number on a certain page of a report, but have it counted

Tags: page-numbering, abstract, front-matter

In a report document class, I would like to hide the numbering on a certain page in the front matter, but still have that page counted in the document wide page numbering scheme.

Specifically, my thesis program wants the Abstract to not have page numbering on it, but still wants it included with its page number in the table of contents.

Right now, this is a minimum example of what I have:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}
\null\vskip 0.75in
\begin{center}
\textbf{\Large Abstract}\\
\end{center}
TEXT OF ABSTRACT

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Summary}
SOME TEXT
\section{More Stuff}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As shown above, the Abstract page appears in the Table of Contents on page iv. I want this, except on page iv I do not want the page number printed at bottom.

I tried gobbling the pagenumber, which does remove the number from the abstract page, but also causes the Abstract to show up in the TOC as a blank.

Lastly, I'm not using the built-in abstract functions because my thesis program wants some specific formatting in the abstract that I was most easily able to implement myself.

Comment: Use `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the abstract page.

Comment: @esdd That worked. You should put that in an answer.

Comment: We have such questions basically every other day...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, now you have one answered. Close them as duplicates and the page links will push the appropriate answer up on PageRank and Google. I only asked because I searched the site (and Google) and didn't find esdd's simply and correct answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Seriously, if this is a problem, someone with high reputation should take the time to close all [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Cthispagestyle%5C%7Bempty%5C%7D) as duplicates, and point them all to the single best answer; perhaps [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34934/add-a-new-empty-page/34935#34935).

Comment: @kingledion: If I would have a Gold Hammer Badge for 'page-numbering' I would have closed it, most likely.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is including `\thispagestyle{empty}` as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vskip 0.75in
\begin{center}
\textbf{\Large Abstract}\\
\end{center}
TEXT OF ABSTRACT

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Summary}
SOME TEXT
\section{More Stuff}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\end{document}
```